# Need help about htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have wrote this rule in my htacces.. the rules redirect to correct url, but browser give me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error...
How can I correct my rule?

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/172-cuccioli-allo-specchio/detail/(.*) https://www.allevamentochihuahua.com/foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/172-cuccioli-allo-specchio/detail/$3 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use END flag because currently your rule is running over again because new url is again matching with our rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/172-cuccioli-allo-specchio/detail/([^/]+)$ https://www.allevamentochihuahua.com/foto-album-nostri-chihuahua/172-cuccioli-allo-specchio/detail/$3 [R=301,NC,L,END]
```

Reference:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end